# Scoped storage Open File downloaded Using Broadcast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider, scoped-storage

I have struggled with this scoped storage and i can't get around it, I'm new to android.
I am working on application where by i want to download a file and on open it automatically by forcing an app chooser(allow user to choose a suitable application to open that downloaded file).
I was able to the downloading the file
this is my code

```
class DownloadActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val url: String = "https://www.google.com/index.html"
    private val fileName: String = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
    private var lastDownload = 0L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val manager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download)
        val dlButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.dlButton)
        dlButton.setOnClickListener {
            lastDownload = downloadFile()
        }

    }

    private fun downloadFile(): Long {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            .setTitle(fileName)
            .setDescription("Downloading...")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)

        val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }


// code to open the file
    fun openFile(activity: AppCompatActivity, selectedFile: File) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, selectedFile)
        val mime = "*/*"

        val fileIntent = Intent()
        fileIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        fileIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

        fileIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
        
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
        startActivity(chooserIntent)

    }
}



My android manifest 

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".DownloadActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show where and when and how you call openFile(). Especially show how you determine the value of parameter selectedFile. Also first tell in which directory the file is downloaded.

Comment: its just a placeholder